# Function graphs comparison

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm asking a graph question that has bothered me a while. I'm considering two graphs here:

$$ y=(x+2)^2 $$
$$ y=x^2 + 4 $$

As can be seen, both the difference is a mere $4x$. I would like to know if we were to draw out the graphs, the graph with an additional $4x$ causes the graph to be behind the one without $4x$. Also, for any real value of $x$, why would the difference between the two graphs increase when $x \lt 2$?  Does it have to do with rates of change? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The difference (by which I mean the absolute value of the differences) increases when $x$ moves away from $0$--that's obvious by the difference which is $\left|4x\right|$.  And the the two graphs are the same: the first, $y = \left(x + 2\right)^2$, is a regular parabola shifted to the left by two and the second, $y = x^2 + 4$, is a regular parabola shifted to up by four.  The only reason the first is "behind" the first is because they are the same and the first one starts to the left *and* below the second.

Comment: so is there any relationship to 4x and the moving of the graph to behind? ( like 4 units of x)? So if it is x^2+ 2x+4, how would the difference of 2x to both equations i stated above affect the grpah? Sorry noob here!

Comment: No, it's already written in terms of a translation of a parabola $y = x^2$: $y = x^2 + 4$ and $y = (x - -2)^2$.  Usually you go backwards and are given $y = x^2 + 4x + 4$ and you need to complete the square to see the translation.